# How to I delay or slow down transition between view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

So I have a button on screen that is connected through storyboards with a push Segway. I press the button and it goes to the next view controller.

If I wanted to slow the transition up by say 1-2 seconds how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a method in your first view controller that uses the performSegueWithIdentifier method after a delay.

You then connect the button on the view controller to that method.

Code example:

**Storyboard**

Here I have the initial view controller with a manual segue to the second view controller.

[image]

I've connected the Fire Method button to an IBAction on the initial view controller, with this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// This method is connected to the Fire Method button
@IBAction func fireMethodBttnTouched(sender: AnyObject) {

    let delay = 1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showSecondViewController", sender: self)
    }
}

}
```

You can adjust the delay constant as needed.

Comment: can you show me an example? I am still pretty new at this! Thanks

Comment: Thanks bro it worked perfect! Is there a rule when to use Dispatch? Or can I use it as many  times as I want throughout my project? Thanks

Comment: @JakeC you can use it whenever you want, you can also create your own queues in place of the main queue and you should also check out NSOperation and NSOperationQueue where you can even have operations that depend on each other before they execute.